# Robotframework-SudsLibrary : URLError <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)>

Tags: robotframework, suds

I'm Workings on SOAP by Robotframework-SudsLibrary.

Python version :2.7.13

SudsLibrary version :0.8

This is the Code:

```
*** Settings ****
Library  SudsLibrary
Library  XML

*** Test Cases ****
Connection
     Create Soap Client  http://X.X.X.X:8080/axis2/services/BSServicesV20?wsdl
     ${WsdlObject}   Create Wsdl Object  InitApp
     log  ${WsdlObject}  console=True
     ${SheetGuide_AttributeValue}   Get Wsdl Object Attribute  ${WsdlObject}  AppID
     Set Wsdl Object Attribute  ${WsdlObject}  PosCondCode  05
     Set Wsdl Object Attribute  ${WsdlObject}  TerminalID  62051023
     Set Wsdl Object Attribute  ${WsdlObject}  UserName  tatTestUser
     Set Wsdl Object Attribute  ${WsdlObject}  Password  tat321Test$$
     log  ${WsdlObject}  console=True
     Call Soap Method  InitApp  ${WsdlObject}

     ${receive_xml}  Get Last Received
```

And this is my Error:

```
URLError: urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

Comment: The URL called uses the HTTP protocol, where the error complains about an SSL certificate. Can you confirm that the example uses the correct protocol? If this is the case, when you use soapUI to send the same message you don't get the same error? Is there a proxy configured to be used by Python (i.e. environment variables: HTTPS_PROXY)?

Comment: Thank you A. Kootstra,
I used to test by soapUI- i have no error and need no certificate,

Comment: I have problem on Robotframework-SudsLibrary!! in soapUI have no problem,No i haven't set any HTTP-Proxy Environment Variable!

Comment: Using exclamation marks (!) in the way you do is considered rude by many, as it appears you're shouting. Please be aware that people here are helping in their own free time, and are not paid to do so. So, when we ask questions or request clarifications, we do so for good reason.

Comment: With respect to the problem at hand, can you sniff your network traffic to see what the actual interactions are between Python and the external system. I find Nirsoft [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) very easy to use, but [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and Telerik [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) are great tools as well.

Comment: Dear  A. Kootstra thank you for your help, in our country we talk by surprise not by complain, and it just a mistake to undemanding each other by text....So take my apologize.
As you said and as i know opensource library and stackoverflow  is not place for complaining...i want to thank you for your help. thank you for introducing the tools.